# Carto Torque animation map for polyline

Tags: carto, torque

I have a polyline shapefile with time series data. I want to create an animation map using Carto and show the line width based on the value. I used to create an animation map for point data and it worked. I updated the code to accommodate polyline setting. However, I tried torque this time and it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?

```
Map {
  -torque-frame-count: 64;
  -torque-animation-duration: 30;
  -torque-time-attribute: "datetime";
  -torque-aggregation-function: "CDB_Math_Mode(torque_category)";
  -torque-resolution: 4;
  -torque-data-aggregation: linear;
}

#layer {
  line-color: #4CC8A3;
  line-width: 1.5;
  line-opacity: 1;
  line-comp-op: multiply;
}


#layer[frame-offset=1] {
  line-width: 8;
  line-opacity: 0.45;
}

#layer[frame-offset=2] {
  line-width: 10;
  line-opacity: 0.225;
}

#layer {
  comp-op: source-over;
  line-opacity: 0.9;
  line-color: #FFF;
  line-width: 1.5;
}

#layer[value=1] {
  line-width: 1.5;
  line-color: #ffeda0;
}

#layer[value=2] {
  line-width: 3.0;
  line-color: #f03b20;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Torque only supports point geometries. In order to animate polygon or line datasets, you will need to create a custom web map application with [CARTO VL](https://carto.com/developers/carto-vl/examples/#example-animate-by-date-range).